# How do I create dynamic links in Knockout.?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to make a button clickable with a different URL depending on which outcomes are selected. At the moment my code shown below sends all links to http://example.com. I would like to make this change depending on which selections have been chosen by the user.

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-corner" type="submit" data-bind="click: startOver, visible: queryData().id > 0">Start over</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container main">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="c12 text-center">
            <h1 data-bind="text: queryData().text"></h1>
            <h3 data-bind="text: queryData().subhead"></h3>
            <h3><a data-bind="text: queryData().link, attr: {href: url}"></a></h3>
            <div class="option-group" data-bind="foreach: queryData().answers">
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" data-bind="click: $parent.goToTarget, text: text"></button>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-bind="click: stepBack, visible: navHistory().length > 1">Previous Step</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-bind="click: buyBook, visible: navHistory().length > 1">Buy the book</button> 
                 </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="push"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js?v=0.4.0"></script>

    <script>

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript is below:

```
var queries = [{  
id: 0,
text: "Start?",
answers: [{
text: "Let's Start!",
target: 1
}]
}, {
id: 1,
text: "Which sectiondo you want",
  answers: [{
     text: "Foo",
     target: 2
    }, {
      text: "Bar",
      target: 3
    }, {
      text: "Foobar",
      target: 4
    }]
  }, {
   id: 2,
   text: "Selection1",
    link: "test2.com",
   answers: []
}];




function QueryViewModel() {
  var self = this; 

  self.url = ko.observable("https://example.com");
  self.querySet = ko.observable();
  self.currentStep = ko.observable();
  self.queryData = ko.observable();
  self.sfw = ko.observable();
  self.navHistory = ko.observableArray();

  // Operations
  self.goToTarget = function(obj) {
  self.navHistory.push(self.currentStep());
  self.currentStep(obj.target);
  self.queryData(self.querySet()[obj.target]);
}

  self.startOver = function() {
    self.navHistory.removeAll();
    self.goToTarget({target: 0});
  }

  self.stepBack = function() {
    var lastStep = self.navHistory().length > 1 ? self.navHistory.pop() : 0;
    self.currentStep(lastStep);
    self.queryData(self.querySet()[lastStep]);
  }

  this.buyBook = function() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
  }

  var paramsString = document.location.hash.substring(1);
  var params = new Array();
  if (paramsString) {
  var paramValues = paramsString.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
  var paramValue = paramValues[i].split("=");
  params[paramValue[0]] = paramValue[1];
}
   }

  params ? paramTarget = params['target'] : params = [];


  self.sfw() ? self.querySet(queriesSFW) : self.querySet(queries);
  if (paramTarget) {
    self.navHistory.push(0);
    self.currentStep(0);
    self.goToTarget({target: paramTarget})
  } else {
    self.goToTarget({target: 0});
  }
}


ko.applyBindings(new QueryViewModel());
```

At present the link2.com redirects to example.com I would like to replace the URL with the entry in the link2 attribute, so in this case test2.com but for other cases it would take the string shown for link and use that.

Comment: You managed to get the header `text` from the object; can't you do the same for the `link`? `<a data-bind="text: queryData().link, attr: { href: queryData().link }"></a>`

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. Not sure how I overlooked this but appreciate the assistance.